# Populating missing times in MySQL data set

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table with columns of timestamp, price, and ticker. Every timestamp value falls on a minute boundary, but not all minutes are present in the data.  The rows for these minutes are not present.

Is there a pure-SQL way to populate a missing minute's row with the price from the next row that *is* populated?

An improvement still, would be for only the minutes between 9:30am EDT and 4:00pm EDT inclusive to be repopulated in this way.

Comment: Are the rows missing?  Or are the rows for all minutes there with just the data missing on the row?

Comment: Yes the rows are missing, sorry for not making that clearer. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rows are in the data, but not the values, the following gets the previous value for a row:

```
select t.timestamp,
       coalesce(value, 
                (select value
                 from t t2
                 where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp and t2.value is not null
                 order by t2.timestamp desc
                 limit 1
                )
               ) as value
from t;
```

You can readily put this into an update:

```
update t join
       (select t.timestamp,
               (select value
                from t t2
                where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp and t2.value is not null
                order by t2.timestamp desc
                limit 1
               ) as value
        from t
       ) toupdate
       on t.timestamp = toupdate.timestamp
    set t.value = toupdate.value;
```

EDIT:

If the rows are missing, then you need to replicate them.  Assuming just one is missing in a row, then the following gets the values:

```
select t.timestamp + interval 1 minute, value
from t left outer
     t tnext
     on tnext.timestamp = t.timestamp + interval 1 minute;
where tnext.timestamp is null
```

You can insert these into an `insert`:

```
insert into t(timestamp, value)
    select t.timestamp + interval 1 minute, value
    from t left outer
         t tnext
         on tnext.timestamp = t.timestamp + interval 1 minute;
    where tnext.timestamp is null;
```

For gaps larger than 1 minute, I would suggest simply repeated the `insert` until no new rows are found.